# JavaFX: Scene Builder like a component?

Tags: java, custom-controls, javafx, scenebuilder

is it possible to use a Scene Builder like a component? I would include an advanced wizard for creating custom layout and save configuration on file or is it better to create a custom one? Is there any third party library which can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

SceneBuilder is now an open source project.
Binaries for SceneBuilder are now available through [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-supports-scene-builder/).
SceneBuilder was split into two parts:

1. SceneBuilderKit (a reusable framework)
2. SceneBuilder (the actual SceneBuilder application, built using the framework).

SceneBuilder source is currently still hosted as part of the JavaFX source repository (which is also open source).  The current development version of SceneBuilder based upon Java 9 development efforts is located at:

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/apps/scenebuilder

Work was done on the SceneBuilder application itself so that it is able to be embedded into an IDE directly rather than needing to run as a stand-alone application (though it can also still run as a stand-alone application).

**The rest of this answer is mostly obsolete**

> is it possible to use a Scene Builder like a component?

[SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) is a closed source standalone application and cannot (currently) be embedded in an existing JavaFX scene graph for a non-Oracle application (as far as I am aware).

You can launch SceneBuilder as a separate application (such as is performed with the current integration of [Scene Builder and Java IDEs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/jsbpub-use_java_ides.htm)).

You likely do not have license rights to distribute Scene Builder (you can [check the Scene Builder license yourself](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/thirdpartylicense-1508136.html)).  If you choose to require the user to use SceneBuilder, you will need to request that they download SceneBuilder from Oracle and install it themselves before using your application.

If you have a significant application you want to bundle SceneBuilder with or embed SceneBuilder into, you can contact Oracle to discuss alternate licensing agreements.

> Is there any third party library which can be used?

Currently, there is no 3rd party library (for JavaFX development) which comes even remotely close to the functionality provided by SceneBuilder.

> I would include an advanced wizard for creating custom layout and save configuration on file or is it better to create a custom one?

This part of your question is too vague to get an answer.

You can create a new question, but [please ensure your new question is of better quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  Requests for somebody to perform an evaluation of options for you on StackOverflow usually don't work out too well (there are other sites for such questions).  It is better to pick an option yourself, try it and then post questions (often with code) when something specific in your implementation is not working for you.

I would note that creating a custom layout manager similar in functionality to SceneBuilder is a large and complex task.  SceneBuilder took a team of people years to create.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that I accept. For our purposes it is enough an anchorpane with ability to place some controls (textfield, label, combo and a few others) and we must give possibility to specify some properties (like font, size..); In the past we have developed a custom "GUI Builder" (but for our component not for javafx) and now we need to do something similar (yes, we are a software house) so before evaluating whether to convert the old project we wanted to know if it was a solution use scene builderor if any other project (commercial or open) was available for evaluation.

Comment: But if i can.. I think that on SO there is the possibility to ask generic questions, not everyone knows what you or I know. So when you say "It is better to pick an option yourself, try it and then post questions when something specific in your implementation is not working" how is possibile to do if I don't know all options that are available? For this SO is important (this is my idea and I hope you think so). And sorry for my bad English (that I'm currently studying, even if i'm old .. oops).